# Is it okay to overwork in partnership?

Tags: professionalism, startup, workload

We are a startup. We are four partners. It's a big project. Two of us are for marketing work and two for development. We have made our plans as they should be. Proper and with a deadline.

I'm working on the back end and almost delivering the work on time. However as we've divided the work front end goes with another developer. But, instead of doing that he is busy in doing some client's work which was brought by one of those marketing partner.

This marketing team partner is the one who have given the idea of the project. He states that for some income and client relations they have to do that. Which will indirectly will help our company to succeed through connections.

Now the situation is that. I have to work on front end too along with the back end work. As another developer is a newbie and have to teach him when he will join me after the client's work.

What I suppose to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a meeting with all stakeholders, you need to sort out responsibilities and deadlines properly AND STICK TO THEM. If sales is changing the game plan partway through on the technical team, then you have a serious problem and your startup will find itself in trouble.

A newbie doing the frontend of a big project is a concern in itself, but if he/she is taking orders from another partner then you all need to meet.

Answer (score 0):

Read this book:

**The Partnership Charter: How To Start Out Right With Your New Business Partnership (or Fix The One You're In) by David Gage**

[https://www.amazon.com/Partnership-Charter-Start-Right-Business/dp/0738208981/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0738208981)

It's by an arbitrator who helps adjudicate the dissolutions of partnerships.

By the time partners get to him, it's usually too late. So he wrote a book to make sure that potential partners asked each other very tough questions before they start a new business together.